# Update an empty field from another table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, field

I am looking for some MYSQL help on updating an empty field from another table.

I would like to allocate a number from the Spare_Mobile_Numbers table to any user with a blank in the user_table.MobileNumber.

I have a table of user data:

```
User_table (table)
----------------------------------------------
Name    Email               MobileNumber
Rob     rob@email.com       <blank>
Jane    jane@email.com      07700000001
Penny   Jenny@email.com     07700000002
John    John@email.com      <blank>
Gavin   Gavin@email.com     07700000003

Spare_Mobile_Numbers (table)
----------------------------------------------
07700000004
07700000005
07700000006
07700000007
```

I would like to allocate a number from the Spare_Mobile_Numbers table to any user with a blank in the user_table.MobileNumber.

Comment: Then the entries in spare_mobile_numbers would be innaccurate, since some of them  would no longer be spare... is that a problem?

Comment: Do you have a `user_name` or `user_id` column in `Spare_Mobile_Numbers`?

Comment: You can't really do this in a single query, because you can't update the spare table as you assign the numbers, so you'd need some kind of a loop to allocate a spare number and then mark it as unavailable.

Comment: Q: Do you have a user_name or user_id - A: NO, I have no way of making a match between the two tables. Q: in spare_mobile_numbers would be innaccurate, since some of them would no longer be spare... is that a problem? - A: NO

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do this in a transaction, because after the spare number is assign you need to remove it from the available list.

Make sure you use a transactional engine like InnoDB.

And do:

```
START TRANSACTION;
  UPDATE user_table u
  INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, @urank:= @urank + 1 as rank 
              FROM user_table u3
              CROSS JOIN (select @urank:= 1) q
              WHERE u3.MobileNumber IS NULL) u2) u1 ON (u.id = u1.id)
  INNER JOIN (SELECT @smrank:= @smrank +1 as rank, sparenumber 
              FROM spare_mobile_numbers
              CROSS JOIN (select @smrank:= 1) q2) sm ON (u1.rank = sm.rank)
  SET u.MobileNumber = sm.sparenumber;

  DELETE sm FROM spare_mobile_numbers sm 
  INNER JOIN user_table u ON (sm.sparenumber = u.MobileNumber);
COMMIT;
```

I've made a few assumptions here:

1. `user_table.id` is the primary key, if it is not use the real PK instead or use `user_table.email` as the join condition. "`u1 ON (u.email = u1.email)`"
2. sparenumber is the name of the field listed in `spare_mobile_numbers`.

Note that MySQL does not allow you to update a table, whilst selecting from that table in a subselect at the same time. Strangly it does allow you to use that same table in a sub-subselect, which is what I'm doing here.

Comment: Small problem Johan '@urank:= 1
              WHERE u3.MobileNumber IS NULL)  u1 ON (u.id = u1.id)
  I' at line 4

Comment: aagghh - i am really sorry Johan, ive been trying work this code out but to no avail.  i have a new error. #1054 - Unknown column 'u.rank' in 'on clause'

Comment: @user965526 Sorry for that, updated the code.

Comment: Simply Awesome - that has been a real help.  Thank you!!